# Bootstrap 3 'Toggle navigation' button alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to create navigation which will center `.navbar-toggle` at the middle of `.navbar-header` upon a small screen breakpoints.

I'm quite new to the CSS and I've been fighting with this minor task for hours already, without any success: here's the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tjc3vhw2/2/), picture included.

An additional minor question: I also would like to center content vertically in this bootstrap `.navbar`, for the time being I've just used `padding-top:` to approximately align buttons and project name, but it does feel somewhat shabby solution, I've tried `vertical-align:` without any success either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    ...

    .navbar-header > .navbar-toggle {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/tjc3vhw2/3/)

To do the vertical centering in your followup, either do some custom padding as you describe, or apply more CSS table display properties as needed. Frankly, the first option is probably the simplest.